# Passing parameter from a Linux script to Android

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, wifi

So, I have a headless Android device tethered to a Linux (Xubuntu) system. I am using adb to manage and control the Android device. I am trying to create some scripts to automate the connection of the device to Wi-fi. I enter the following commands in the Android interactive shell to make the connection:

```
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 remove_network all                     
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 add_network                            
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 ssid '"Fubar-24"'
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN            
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE            
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 list_networks                          
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 enable_network 0                       
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 reconnect
```

For some reason I need all those quotes around the SSID in line 3. I'm not sure why.
And it works. 
As long as every network I want to connect to is named Fubar-24.
So I created the following script and named it "test_open.sh" and push it to the Android's /system/bin directory.

```
#! /bin/bash
#Some things I have tried
#SSID="'"'"'$1'"'"'"
#SSID=\'\"$1\"\'
SSID="'\""$1"\"'"
#SSID=$1
echo "using SSID: $SSID"
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 remove_network all                     
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 add_network                            
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 ssid $SSID
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN            
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE            
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 list_networks                          
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 enable_network 0                       
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 reconnect
```

Then I call it from the Linux shell, like so:

```
adb shell sh /system/bin/test_open.sh tenda692
```

Where 'tenda692 is the SSID of the network I want to connect to.  Here is the result:

```
gordon:~/Desktop$ adb shell sh /system/bin/test_open.sh tenda692
using SSID: '"tenda692"'
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
0
Using interface 'wlan0'
FAIL
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0        any    [DISABLED]
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
Using interface 'wlan0'
OK
gordon:~/Desktop$
```

Notice the FAIL response for the 3rd wpa_cli command, and the lack of an SSID for the network in the Network list. Also, the echo command expands $SSID properly. As you can see from the embedded comments, I have been trying several different variations on attaching quotes to the parameter string. And no quotes at all. 
I'm banging my head against the wall here, folks. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the question and I was trying to figure out which combination of SSID quotes is working ..

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is this:

wpa_cli needs to see the ssid argument as "fubar-24", but if you use the command

```
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 ssid "Fubar-24"
```

the shell will strip the quotes off of the "Fubar-24" and you will get:

```
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 ssid Fubar-24
```

You solved this by putting single quotes around the double quotes. The problem with this is the is prevents $SSID from being evaluated and turned into "Fubar-24". Instead, '"$SSID"' becomes "$SSID". A better way is backslash the quotes. This causes the shell to pass the quotes through to the application. Like this:

```
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 ssid \"Fubar-24\"
```

This is better and allows the shell to expand a variable inside the quotes.

This works:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

#
# connect to the wifi network specified in the argument
#
echo "using SSID: $1"
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 remove_network all
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 add_network
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 ssid \"$1\"
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 set_network 0 key_mgmt NONE
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 list_networks
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 enable_network 0
wpa_cli ifname=wlan0 reconnect
```